# Xcode Playgrounds Shared Directory Not Working

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, xcode10, xcode11

When creating an Xcode Playground, the supported playgroundSharedDataDirectory does not properly show my the expected directory.

Expected: ~/Documents/Shared Playground Data

Actual: file:///var/folders/46/zg_mg07d5h5_9t6q_4vr9_2w0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-BEF6F13E-994E-45C9-A18E-7DE953069D69/Documents/Shared%20Playground%20Data/

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

print(playgroundSharedDataDirectory)
```

This also does not link to the directory. If I place a file in the correct directory, I cannot read it. If I place it in the directory, it does work, but it changes every time the playground is loaded.

Xcode 10.3, also appears in Xcode 11. This worked in 10.2

Comment: The playgroundSharedDataDirectory  points to different paths depending if you selected a iOS or macOS playground. Xcode 11 does not symlink automatically. Problems:  the Playgrounds in iOS will create a new Document directory everytime and it will NOT symlink with the User/:user/Document directory.
playgroundSharedDataDirectory will contains the path to “Shared Data Directory” which will not exist because you will not be creating everytime a new folder right? better to use `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]`

Comment: But this is pain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the path that iOS playground use. If you make a macOS playground it will have the path `~/Documents/Shared Playground Data`

Comment: So, in iOS - if I want to write a file that I created in an iOS playground (e.g. audiorecording.wav) to disk and access it from any other application on the iDevice, where do I have to store the .wav file to? Is there a url for the iOS playground/folder that I can access when opening the playground container file  in the files app, or can I even write to any place in the files app directly from my code?