# Xcode 11 iOS playgrounds no longer symlink playgroundSharedDataDirectory - bug or feature?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground, xcode11

Xcode 11 Playgrounds seemingly changed the behavior of `playgroundSharedDataDirectory`:

To reproduce, paste the below in a playground and execute it in Xcode 10 and Xcode 11 respectively:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

print(playgroundSharedDataDirectory)
let str = try String(contentsOf: playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("data.json")) // assuming you create  ~/Documents/Shared Playground Data/data.json
```

`playgroundSharedDataDirectory` resolves to:

**Xcode 11.2:**

- iOS: `file:///Users/:username/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices/DB897D66-E542-44BD-B6CF-0176A3E480A9/data/Containers/Data/Application/2F952093-BD81-4B0C-AD45-8B5E45B4D7AB/Documents/Shared%20Playground%20Data/` ❌
- macOS: `file:///Users/:username/Documents/Shared%20Playground%20Data/` ✅

**Xcode 10.2.1:**

- iOS: `file:///var/folders/s7/x9ltynsn2zg_djfbtzszhn8d4zn6gb/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-5985DF99-2BFE-45AC-9F34-70620F1DCD17/Documents/Shared%20Playground%20Data/` ✅
- macOS: `file:///Users/:username/Documents/Shared%20Playground%20Data/` ✅

Where in Xcode 10.2.1, iOS playgrounds symlink to `~/Documents/Shared Playground Data`, it no longer does in Xcode 11+.

I'm wondering, is this an intentional change? If so, how can I access shared files from an iOS playground?

PS: I saw the answer to a related question (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57981133/1324861), however, the answer isn't really applicable if the code I'm running requires an iOS playground.

Comment: Have you gotten any further? I am also trying to find a URL that I can write a file (that my iOS Playground created) to and make this file accessible to other Apps on the iPad. Either by opening the Playground in a File Manager App and retrieving my file from some subdirectory there or from someplace in the Files App, in case it were accessible from within my Playground code.